# why does the statement [1,2] < [2,1] evaluate to True in python

Tags: python

I have recently started studying python programming language and in the process come across the following statement :

> [1,2] < [2,1] evaluating to
>       True

I seem not to figure out how the comparison is being done internally by python.

Comment: The comparison is done by the list version of the `__gt__` method.  A class may define an ordering method.  Numbers, lists do, dictionaries don't.  A relevant documentation section: https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#comparisons

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The comparison is made item by item in each `list`:

```
>>> [1, 2] < [2, 1] # 1 < 2: because the first two items differ, comparison ends here
True
>>> [1, 2] == [1, 2] # 1 == 1 and 2 == 2
True
>>> [1, 2][0] < [2, 1][0] # 1 < 2
True
>>> [1, 2][1] > [2, 1][1] # 2 > 1
True
```

More about [Comparing Sequences and Other Types](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#comparing-sequences-and-other-types):

> Sequence objects may be compared to other objects with the same sequence type. The comparison uses lexicographical ordering: first the first two items are compared, and if they differ this determines the outcome of the comparison; if they are equal, the next two items are compared, and so on, until either sequence is exhausted. If two items to be compared are themselves sequences of the same type, the lexicographical comparison is carried out recursively. If all items of two sequences compare equal, the sequences are considered equal.

Comment: Your first line comment is misleading, since the result is of the comparison `True` because of the first elements in the list and independently of the remaining.

Comment: @MaxPowers, agree :) Edited the comment.

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure this is a duplicate somewhere, but when you're comparing lists, the comparison is being done [lexicographically by each element](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#comparing-sequences-and-other-types). Python first compares 1 to 2, the first elements of each list. This is true, so the right list is greater than the left.